# Any context-free grammar generating a regular language is unambiguous

Tags: automata, context-free, ambiguity

I am not sure whether this statement is true or not. Could there be an example of CFG generating a regular language and is ambiguous?

Comment: Well, of course. Just make some redundant rules

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the grammar:

> $S\to aS\mid Sa\mid \varepsilon$

or even simpler, the grammar:

> $S\to S \mid \varepsilon$

Comment: ok, so the first is a CFG, and it's ambiguous and generates a regular language. Is that correct?

Comment: This is the case for both.